# Highcharts - Adding a point with addPoint stretches time

Tags: charts, highcharts, angular2-highcharts

When you spam click `Add Point` on the `JSFiddle` below, you will see that it does not respect the time interval, and instead it stretches the time.

https://jsfiddle.net/ouc2x3ng/1/

I have read this: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-irregular-time, and I can't see what is so special that makes it work.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to disable the `ordinal` property for `xAxis`, which is enabled in Highstock by default:

```
xAxis: {
    ordinal: false
},
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/apscbLjn/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.ordinal